# Table used in which stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have multiple database restored one is master and other are version DB (`TesDB, TestDB1,TestDB2 etc...`)

I want to know one particular table is used in which stored procedure.  I need list for databases.

Currently I am using below query but it's working only for one DB at a time.

```
use [TestDB]
GO

SELECT Name 
FROM sys.Procedures 
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) = 'Testtable'
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like?

```
declare @db varchar(50),
        @sql nvarchar(max),
        @tofind varchar(max)='table to find'

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db   


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    set @sql='SELECT Name,OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID)FROM '+@db+'.sys.Procedures WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) like ''%'+@tofind+'%''  '
    print @sql

    exec sp_executesql @sql
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Redgate's Sql Search tool. It's fantastic for stuff like this.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Answer (score -1):

exec sp_MSforeachdb 'use ? SELECT ? as DBName, Name FROM sys.Procedures WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) = ''Testtable'''